# Can the iOS enterprise app development program be used to distribute apps to other companies but not via the app store?

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

If a company has an iOS app that it wants to distribute to its customers, but it doesn't want that app to be submitted to the app store and subject to the App Store submission criteria, then can it use the Enterprise app development program to do that? - or is the enterprise program strictly for app development and distribution within a company?

Comment: You can give your binary to them to distribute it using their own Enterprise account. I guess you need to sign it with their key.

Comment: Its not one customer, its numerous

Comment: If this is off topic then why does the category of app store exist under which questions can be categorized? Why not remove that category then.

Comment: @Mr.Peckington Considering that this Q is about Apple's iOS enterprise development program, it really doesn't have anything to do with the [tag:appstore] tag. Even if it did, the fact that *this* question is off topic doesn't necessarily mean that all questions related to app stores are off topic.

Answer (score 0):

This is all spelled out pretty clearly in the information Apple provides about the enterprise program. For example, you can [start with this page](https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/enterprise/) which says unambiguously:

> **You plan to only distribute your iOS apps within your company or organization**

There's much more detail in the enterprise program agreement.

Comment: What is the solution in this situation then? The app would be a web page wrapped in an iOS native shell - something that is not permitted according to App Store guidelines and its not intended for general consumer downloading or purchasing. So if the Enterprise developer system can't be used, how can the app be distributed to customers?

Comment: Depends on the nature of the relationship between the developer and the customer. Typically, the client subscribes to the enterprise program and provides the distribution provision and key to the developer. Either that, or the developer does the work and provides the code to the client. A third possibility in the US is to go through the app store and use the volume purchase option, but that's quite different from what you're asking about.

Comment: @Aminoacids Android. Android is the solution

Comment: @Clint Android is not without it's own issues. This question is 4 years old and the distribution landscape has changed considerably. These days, developers wanting to distribute to other companies but not to the general public should go through the [B2B app store](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/).

Comment: @Caleb Which requires Apple review.

Comment: @Clint Them's the breaks. But if someone *has* an iOS app that they want to distribute to customers, Android is certainly *not* the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do that. The devices from the other company just need your distribution provisioning profiles. We did that in my previous company a lot. 
Not sure if it's officially legal though.

Comment: That violates your agreement with Apple. I would proceed with caution.

Comment: Yes, but it's technically possible. I know some companies that do it although it violates the agreement. But you're right, it's pretty risky.