# How to distribute ios app to my European enterprise customers NOT through appstore

Tags: ios, distribution, enterprise

We have created a messaging app and regularly post updates to the appstore. This way, appstore contains always the latest & greatest, with a small risk of bugs.

We want to build a stable version for our business customers (who do in-house messaging), which updates very seldom or never. Our customers want to control the rate of updates themselves.

Telling their employees **not to upgrade** does not work, since new installs always get the latest version from the appstore.

Question:

1. Can I use the enterprise distribution certificate of my own company and deliver the app binaries to my customers (e.g. a different binary per customer)?
2. Or should I create a different version in the appstore for each customer?
3. Or should I force my customers to request their own enterprise distribution certificate, which is a hassle I would like to avoid?

I guess that the answer to my first question is NO, as indicated in [Can the iOS enterprise app development program be used to distribute apps to other companies but not via the app store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625553/can-the-ios-enterprise-app-development-program-be-used-to-distribute-apps-to-oth)

2 is annoying, since everybody in the world can see & install the app

3 is annoying, since it requires time of my customer plus a legal contract such that I can request a certificate for my customer, use their private key, ...

Answer (score 3):

By your contract you are not allowed to do that.

But Everybody does it. And i had phone contact with a apple employe which told me that they won't go behind that case.

And imaging: should apple check all installations of all enterprise deployment programs? Impossible,... even for Apple.

I would just try to get not more installations than 1000.

Comment: Now that's interesting. It would save me, my employer and our customers megabytes of paperwork/headaches.

Answer (score 2):

The iOS developer program allows you to distribute Custom B2B Apps directly to your customers if they have Volume Purchase Program account.

> **Custom B2B Apps**
>
> You can also offer custom B2B apps directly to your business customers who have a Volume Purchase Program account. A custom B2B app provides a unique, tailored solution to address a specific business need or requirement.

---

If you have customers who are not located in the US, I recommend the third option: making our customers have their own iOS Enterprise Developer account.

Comment: Last time I checked, the VPP is US only?

Comment: As of 21/02/2013, the Volume Purchasing Program is available in Australia, Canada, France, Germany, Italy, Japan, New Zealand, Spain, United Kingdom, and the United States. http://www.apple.com/business/vpp/